# Fixed template sidebars position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the sidebars on the following template to have fixed position.

Is it possible to do it without using javascript and only css?

[Template Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kFBuD/109/)

PS: Placing position fixed for the sidebards it is not an option because its changing the whole structure of the site and they are placed outside of content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wanna like this??http://jsfiddle.net/kFBuD/1447/

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: you can rewrite the scrollbar make it beautiful

Answer (score 0):

You can using **position:fixed**

```
.sidebar1, .sidebar2 {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    top:0;
    padding-top:60px;
    **position:fixed;**
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: No, that has some unwanted effect because its placing the two sidebars outside the content area.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow` property of HTML if you don't want it in CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: try something like this :

 <div id="scrollable2" style="overflow:auto;height:300px">